# databricks dbx execute - how to check cluster standard error log

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-dbx

When I use databricks connect I can see standard error log via my local shell.
Now I am using databricks dbx, only shows dbx log...
Is there way to check cluster log easily(standard error)?
Standard error/log4j out of databricks cluster

**Update**

when I miss argument :

databricks connect log

```
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: args1
```

dbx log(only about dbx)

```
⠼ Running the entrypoint file[dbx][2023-01-19 10:39:57.445] Execution failed, please follow the given error
╭────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ───────────╮
│ d:\...s\execute.py:144 in execute                      │
│                                                        │
│   141 │   │   upload_via_context=upload_via_context,   │
│   142 │   │   pip_install_extras=pip_install_extras,   │
│   143 │   )                                            │
│ ❱ 144 │   controller_instance.run()                    │
│   145                                                  │
│   146                                                  │
blablabla...
RuntimeError: Command execution failed. Traceback from cluster:
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

I found follow link,
https://github.com/databrickslabs/dbx/issues/112
it says databricks cluster cannot export log right now...
is this true?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried  these steps , method in this document: [Diagnostic logging in Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/audit-logs) ?

**Diagnostic settings:**

[image]

You can configure the collection of following data and connect to respective environment as shown in the below image

[image]

For example if you want  to connect log Analytics
then, configure the diagnostic setting, you can go to Log Analytics Workspace -> Logs -> Log Management-> you will find Databricks notebook -> Run the below query to get the details about the notebook.

```
DatabricksNotebook 

| where TimeGenerated > ago(24h) 

| limit 10
```

**Update:**

You can access these files from the **Driver logs** tab on the data bricks cluster.

Go to **cluster** -> **driver logs** -> Click the name of a log file and download it.

[image]

Comment: it's not related to the question. Diagnostic logging doesn't include cluster logs

Comment: hi @AlexOtt, could you please check this [link](https://i.imgur.com/1lldM8i.png).please correct me if I am wrong. is this databricks cluster is different from cluster log's ?

Comment: yes, it's different. Diagnostic logging only including information about clusters (start/stop/edit/delete/...) but not the actual logs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/clusters-manage#view-cluster-logs

Comment: Please check the above update

Comment: @SaiVamsi, Thanks for your answer, but I know I can see the log at databricks page.
But it is pretty inefficient compare to see in local shell...